# Uncaught ReferenceError при обработки полученных данных

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть код с валидатором формы:

```
$('.login form').submit(function() { // ВАЛИДАЦИЯ ЛОГИНА
    var number = 0;
    $('.login form .form-group input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').each(function() {
        $(this).prev().parent('.input-group').parent('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').removeClass('has-error');
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") {
            $(".bottom-right").notify({
                message: {
                    text: "Поле \"" + $(this).prev().parent('.input-group').prev().text() + "\" не заполненно !"
                },
                type: 'danger',
                fadeOut: {
                    enabled: true,
                    delay: 3000
                },
                closable: false
            }).show();
            $(this).prev().parent('.input-group').prev('label').attr('style', 'color:#ea4525;').parent('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        } else {
            $(this).prev().parent('.input-group').prev('label').attr('style', 'color:#43cb0e;').parent('.form-group').addClass('has-success');
            number = number + 1;
        }
    });
    if (number == 3) {
        var send = $('#form').serialize();
        $('#registersubmit').attr('disabled', '');
        preloader();
        alert(send);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            //dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
            data: send,
        })
        .done(function() {
            console.log(data);
            $('#response').html(data);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            //console.log("error");
            $('#response').html(data);
        })
        .always(function() {
            $('.login form .form-group input[type="text"],input[type="password"]').val('');
            $('#registersubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Отправка происходит нормально, валидация также проходит нормально. Но при попытке добавить ответ в `#response` выдает ошибку:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: send,
     })
.done(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
     $('#response').html(data);
})
.fail(function(data) {
     //console.log(data);
     $('#response').html(data);
})
```

в методе `done()` и `fail()` у вас отсутствуют аргументы, а должны быть. Поэтому значение `data` скрипт и не видит